# Bootstrap walker disabling parent menu with submenus, preventing dropdown from displaying on hove

Tags: php, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

i having trouble with a Bootstrap walker: Dropdown menu won't appear on hover and submenus are disabled for parent menu.otherwise it works. Help needed

Here are my walker

```
class Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    // Start Level
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat( "\t", $depth );
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"dropdown-menu\">\n";
    }

    // Start El
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        // Li tags Attributes
        $li_attributes = '';
        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        // $classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children) ? 'dropdown' : '';
        $classes[] = ($args->walker->has_children && $depth == 0) ? 'dropdown' : '';

        $classes[] = ($item->current || $item->current_item_ancestor) ? 'active' : '';
        $classes[] = 'nav-item';
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = strlen( $id ) ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names . $li_attributes . '>';

        // A attributes
        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= ($args->walker->has_children) ? ' class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"' : ' class="nav-link"';

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= ($args->walker->has_children) ? '<span class="caret"></span></a>' : '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    
}
```

and here is where i print it out in the header.php

```
   <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu(array(
              'menu' => 'primary',
              'depth' => 2,
              'container' => false,
              'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
              'walker' => new Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu(),
            ));

            ?>
          </ul>
```

I've been trying to fix, but without success. I've searched for solutions on Stack Overflow, various websites, and even consulted with ChatGPT, but I still don't quite understand how to put it all together.

Specifically, I'm trying to get the dropdown menu to appear on hover, and allow submenus for the parent menu. I've tried modifying the walker code, adjusting the menu settings, and tinkering with the CSS, but nothing seems to work as expected.

If anyone has experience with Bootstrap walkers and can guide me through the steps to solve this issue, I'd greatly appreciate it!"

Comment: I'd start by checking whether the HTML output this creates, matches the structure this kind of Bootstrap menu needs.